# Vaadin adding child item to treetable

Tags: parent-child, vaadin, treetable

I tried to add a child element to treetable (element is a Bean) but the somehow the result is weird. I put a small example together.

```
     BeanItemContainer<Project> bic = new BeanItemContainer<Project>(Project.class);
 TreeTable projectTable = new TreeTable();
 projectTable.setContainerDataSource(bic);

 bic.addBean(Root);
 bic.addBean(p1);
 bic.addBean(p2);
 bic.addBean(p3);

 projectTable.setParent(p1, Root);
 projectTable.setParent(p2, Root);
 projectTable.setParent(p3, p1);
```

As you can see in the last line p1 should be parent of p3, and the result :[see the pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pop5s.jpg) (p3 become the children of p2)

Code can be accessed from here : goo.gl/BMXiv

There are 2 main files:

TttestApplication.class

Project.class

Cs

Comment: I think you need to provide more code to get help with this.

Comment: More code can be confusing, I need some time to think over what I did.

Comment: Hey Martin, I simplified the example, if you have time pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, I could not get over the issue above, so I load beans by 'addProjectToTree'
and everything happens as usually using addItem.

```
 .... beans' initialization
 Root = new Project("Projects","Indoor","HI", new Date(), new  Date(),this.getNextId(),null);
 ... 
 ... columns' creation
 projectTable.addContainerProperty("description", String.class, "");
 ... 
 ...
 addProjectToTree(Root);    

public Object addProjectToTree(Project p)
{
  Object id = projectTable.addItem(new Object[] {p.getDescription(),p.getKeyword() ...);
    if(p.getParentId()!=null)
    {
        projectTable.setParent(id, p.getParentId());
    }
    return id;
}
```

That's it.

Cs

Comment: The only explanation for your problem in the screenshot is that somehow P3 thought p2 was root (had the same id maybe? )